# How to apply all the font settings on all the windows in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application and I've recently added a new function: FontFamily choose.

What I want is: When selecting a certain FontFamily from the Combobox, it will apply on all the other windows, so how? Notice this is a sub window, maybe the parent window or other windows are still open, and I want to apply it onto all the other windows.

PS: I used something like: FontFamily="{Bind .....}", but it doesn't apply; what's more, there're too many things....I wonder if there's a global way to cope with it?

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all Windows of the application to set their `FontFamily`:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    window.FontFamily = new FontFamily(...);
}
```

The child elements of the Windows would all get the new font due to property value inheritance of the `FontFamily` property.

---

Alternatively, create a global font resource in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="GlobalFont">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

and consume it as a `DynamicResource` in all Windows

```
<Window ... FontFamily="{DynamicResource GlobalFont}">
```

Then change it by

```
Application.Current.Resources["GlobalFont"] = new FontFamily(...);
```